# How to get and format git changelog in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a declarative pipeline setup in Jenkins. In the post-build step, I want to send a beautifully formatted git changelog of the changes since the last build to Discord. There is a plugin for that, easy as a piece of cake:

```
    post {
        always {
            discordSend result: currentBuild.result, title: 'Build ' + env.BUILD_NUMBER, link: env.BUILD_URL, webhookURL: DISCORD_WEBHOOK
        }
        failure {
            discordSend result: currentBuild.result, title: 'Failed Build ' + env.BUILD_NUMBER, link: env.BUILD_URL, webhookURL: DISCORD_FAILED_WEBHOOK            
        }
    }
```

It looks like this:

[image]

The link leads to my Jenkins server where there **is** a detailed changelog since last build. However, I would like to additionally include this changelog to this Discord message.

I was not able to figure out how to do this for **declarative** pipeline.

1. How do I get the changelog?
2. How I format it for Markdown 101?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of examining changesets, this might send you along the right path:

```
@NonCPS
def printCurrentBuildChangesets() {
  def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
  for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
    def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
    for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
        def entry = entries[j]
        echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
        def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
        for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
            def file = files[k]
            echo "${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you may try the following from [Pipeline examples](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#gitcommit_changeset):

```
// This should be performed at the point where you've
// checked out your sources on the agent. A 'git' executable
// must be available.
// Most typical, if you're not cloning into a sub directory
// and invoke this in the context of a directory with .git/
// Along with SHA-1 id of the commit, it will be useful to retrieve changeset associated with that commit
// This command results in output indicating several one of these and the affected files:
// Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R)
commitChangeset = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r HEAD').trim()
```

Formatting it as Markdown and attaching it via `discordSend description: myDescription` is left as an excercise ;)

Comment: I don't see how `diff tree` command will output the difference between the current revision (being built) and the last built revision (that's what Jenkins does internally in the build description). There is no environmental variable available (I know of) that shows the previous build revision id as well.

Comment: You have to figure that out by `entry.commitId` as in the first part.